# Calling jS function in a Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

There is a table consists of different record fetched from database. There is one button in-front of every record.This button is used to open the corresponding record in a modal popup.This modal popup is also used for updating that record.The popup is opening fine but it seems that the js function inside the element of this popup not working.
I have two radio box as 'hard copy' and 'Soft copy' in that modal the moment i click on soft copy  one input type  file should be visisble and on clcik on other button it should be hidden. but it is not working.My js is correct as it is working fine in normal page. What may be reason for this

```
<div id="data1">  <div class="col-md-3 form-group" >
<label><br></label><a href="#" target="_blank">Name<i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="Document" autocomplete="off" >   
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group" style="padding-right:0px;" >
<label for="doctype" >Document Type:</label>

Hard Copy<input type="radio" id="doctype" name="doctype" value="Hard Copy" onclick="text()"required>
Soft Copy<input type="radio" id="doctype" name="doctype" value="Soft Copy" onclick="text()" required>

</div>
<script>
function text() {
var x = document.getElementById("data1");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

1.Is there any special syntax to call the id of modal popup.
2. I have included librarry files in the base page do it need to include them again in the modal popup
3.Any Other information about this type of problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi you can put you js code inside this function like  :document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your code you want to access modal elements by id here
});

Comment: @Jagroop  I tried in that way but no joy. still if you post the correct code for the same i will try with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that the issue might be related to how your modal handles the JavaScript code. You can modify your JavaScript function like this:

```js
function text(type) {
  var x = document.getElementById("data1");
  if (type === 'soft') {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Then update your HTML to pass in the value of hard or soft:

```html
Hard Copy<input type="radio" id="doctype" name="doctype" value="Hard Copy" onclick="text('hard')" required>
Soft Copy<input type="radio" id="doctype" name="doctype" value="Soft Copy" onclick="text('soft')" required>
```

It's worth popping the JavaScript code inside a
`windows.addEventListener('load', () => {...}` function to make sure everything has loaded and is available, or as a minimum, load your JS at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: If your code works on a normal page but not a particular one, have you checked to see if there are any errors in the console? The issue could be related to the fetched content. Could you share the code for how you are fetching the records?

Comment: It is not at all calling now